# How to remove textContent in greasemonkey?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

Ive been trying to use greasemonkey to change the example text on the outlook login page.

Specifically this snip:

```
<div style="cursor: text;" aria-hidden="true" class="placeholder ltr_override" id="idDiv_PWD_UsernameExample">someone@example.com</div>
```

I'm trying to change it to display 'Username' instead, but after trying many things have had no luck.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the URL for the log-in page?  What browser are you using?

Comment: I'm applying it to http*://login.live.com/* and im running FF 28

Comment: I have updated my answer and tested it on login.live.com :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have the username, here is an example:

```
<div style="cursor: text;" aria-hidden="true" class="placeholder ltr_override" 
  id="idDiv_PWD_UsernameExample">someone@example.com</div>


document.getElementById('idDiv_PWD_UsernameExample').textContent = 'whatever you want';
```

Here is the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gV9WS/)

**Update**
After your comment with the URL, the DOM you want to change is produced by JavaScript.. try this

```
window.addEventListener('load', insertData, false);

function insertData() {

  var div = document.getElementById('idDiv_PWD_UsernameExample');

  if (div) {
    div.textContent = 'whatever you want';
  }
}
```

Comment: Returns null when it runs. I also tried it onload, which it never runs.

Comment: That depends on the rest of the code. Do you have the username? Where do you get it? How do you replace it. Above code was an example of what could be done. It also depends on how the data is produced. If it is dynamically produced, the `onload` might be too soon.

Comment: Im only making it say 'Username' instead of someone@example.com, I've tried to do this DOM side as well, I personally don't know where to go from here.